# Will Windows Mobile 5 SDK work for Windows 7.5 mango OS phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, smartphone

I want to develop an application for  Windows 7.5 mango OS phone like HTC Mozart, I am already having Visual Studio 2008, will the apps built by Windows Mobile 5 smartphone SDK be supported in a windows phone?

Comment: Take a look at this [Microsoft Connect entry](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010). The Windows Mobile developer community is not very happy with Microsoft not supporting Windows CE/Mobile development in VS2010 and beyond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the [Windows Phone SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27570) is the only one that is supported.  In short, Windows Mobile != Windows Phone.

Also the UI is drastically different and the underlying runtime and .NET framework is also different. You might be able to port the logic of your code across easily to the new SDK, but the UI will need rewriting.

There are also a lot of freedoms lost in the new iteration as "the user is king". This means you need to review what your current app requires and provides to see if it is even a good fit for the new range of phones.

Comment: If it is like that the programs running on windows mobile will not run on windows phone. Am I right?

Comment: @ArunChettoor Correct, the underlying OS and runtime are entirely distinct.

Comment: @ Adam Houldsworth Thank you for responding. So I hope that from windows phone 7 onwards the programs are not backward compatible. Phew! That makes a lot of programmers efforts to go  into vain.

Comment: @ArunChettoor Yes and no, lots of existing effort doesn't apply to WP7 - the mindset on the phone operation system is different. This story is no different on other platforms.

Comment: @ Adam Houldsworth If it is like that they must just have to compile the old code to port the program to the new one, isn`t it?

Comment: @ArunChettoor Not that simple. Its a different flavour of the .NET framework and a completely new UI stack. Plus the phone has more limitations than it used to. Easiest example: there is no windows registry access in the new OS.

Answer (score 1):

No, Windows mobile SDK wont work for Windows phone 7 applications.

Answer (score 0):

See, the .NET Framework for windows phone 7 has changed completely . Infact the classes and APIs have changed .you can carry forward your previous experience of Windows Phone development into this new one but that certainly might not be the same code and services working in the same platform